# Is there any way to search answers by upvotes (not questions)

Tags: support, answers, search

How can I see what answers have the most upvotes. I know for questions it is possible, but I did not figure out a method for answers. An answer can have lots of upvotes even if the question does not have.

Comment: This is not very clear - what exactly do you mean by "answers have the most upvotes"?

Comment: OP wants to find good answers, not judging them on anything related to the question. (as I read it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter answers by using `is:answer`. So all you have to do is have a 'high' vote count and the `is` directive.

So `is:answer score:900` yields [2 results on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A900).

Comment: thanks for the answer. That was what I was looking for.